Module not found \vite\bin\vite.js
When attempting to run a command or script in my Node.js project, I encountered the following error message
This part of the error message suggests that the command or file path Bookshop\Frontend\my-bookshop\node_modules.bin\ is not being recognized as a valid command or executable file. This could be due to a typo in the command, a missing file, or a misconfiguration.

This is my Packege json  how to fix this error
his error message indicates that Node.js is unable to find the module vite.js in the specified path.
Description: The error occurs when Node.js attempts to load the module vite.js but cannot find it in the expected location. This can happen due to various reasons, such as incorrect path or missing module.
{
  "name": "my-bookshop",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.66",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.22",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.34.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.6",
    "vite": "^5.2.7"
  }
}


Putting an & in your directory name is just asking for trouble

https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4225

What is your node and npm version? do you run "npm install"?

try to remove & from the path to your project or switch to another package manager (e.g. pnpm, yarn). check the Offical DOC

Try to run ./node_modules/.bin/vite
